# Pass added event.data to function

Tags: jquery

I can pass data to a function using event.data within a binding event as shown below :-

***jQuery code***

```
var objKeyboard = {
  init: function( config ) {
    this.config = config;
    this.bindEvents();
  },

  bindEvents: function() {
    this.config.selectedKey.on('change', { idx: 1 }, this.Generate);
  },

  Generate: function(event) {
    alert(event.data.idx);
  }
};

objKeyboard.init({
  selectedKey: $("#selected_key_b"),
});
```

However, how can I pass data to Generate: function(event)

Example:- this.Generate({ idx: 2 });

Thanks kindly!

***Amendment 1***

I want to call Generate: function(event) outside an event handler, example :-

```
init: function( config ) {
  this.config = config;
  this.bindEvents();
  this.Generate({ idx: 1 });
}
```

Comment: If you make a jsfiddle out of it I am willing to play around with it

Comment: Are you just asking how to create the event object to pass to Generate?  Because you can call it in init, just like that.

Comment: If I try and call this.Generate({ idx: 1 }); within init, I get 'TypeError: event.data is undefined'

Comment: Please post your code as a [mcve]

Comment: You're getting 'TypeError: event.data is undefined' because your alert inside your Generate method is accessing `.data` which does not exist. Your alert should be `alert(event.idx);` if you're going to call `this.Generate({ idx: 1 });`.